# Do the intersection of neighborhoods of lines in Euclidean space that pass through the origen are bounded?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology

In the Euclidean space ${R}^n$ consider two lines $l_1$ and $l_2$ that pass through the origin. Given a positive number $\varepsilon >0$ and $i\in \{1,2\}$, define $N(\varepsilon,l_i)=\cup\{B_\varepsilon(x):x\in l_i\}$ (where $B_\varepsilon(x)$ is the $\varepsilon$ ball around $x$). For each $\varepsilon >0$, is $N(\varepsilon,l_1)\cap N(\varepsilon,l_2)$ bounded?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.**

Yes, $N(\varepsilon,l_1)\cap N(\varepsilon,l_2)$ is bounded providing that the lines $l_1,l_2$ are distinct.

To prove it, you can name $\alpha \in (0,\pi/2]$ the angle between the lines and prove that $N(\varepsilon,l_1)\cap N(\varepsilon,l_2) \subset B_{\frac{\epsilon}{\sin(\alpha / 2)}}(0)$

Comment: @mathcounerexampes.net Can you give a hint? I do not see how to do it.

Comment: You need to make a picture to understand that $N(\varepsilon,l_i)$ is an infinite strip of $2 \epsilon$ width and look at the intersection of those two strips.